# How can I rearrage x label in Seaborn Graph in Python

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a problem about rearranging values in x label in seaborn.

Here is my dataframe example shown below.

```
    index   year    value
0   0      -2150    1
1   1      -2000    2
2   2      -1610    1
3   3      -1400    5
...
946 946     2018    20
947 947     2019    23
948 948     2020    9
```

Here is my seaborn code

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
sns.barplot(data=df, x = "year" , y = 'value')
plt.title("Graph", fontsize = 14)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

All year values are listed orderly without using scale or range.

I can use plt.xticks but it doesn't work.

I want to get this order like `-2150,-1500,-1000,-500,0,500,1000,500,1500,2000,2020` in x label

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn creates the bar plot with every entry given the same space, independent whether years are close together or not. So effectively using a categorical x-axis. Internally, the ticks are numbered `0, 1, 2, 3, ...`.

You can create a list of desired labels, and then find the closest matching value in the years to be used as label. The index of the match in the array is also internal x-value of the corresponding bar.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

years = np.sort(np.unique( np.concatenate([np.random.randint(-2150, 1980, 900), np.arange(1990, 2021)])))
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': years, 'value': np.random.randint(1, 20, years.size)})

desired_ticks = [-2150] + list(range(-1500, 2001, 500)) + [2020]
np_years = df.year.to_numpy(dtype=np.int)
desired_ticks_idx = [np.argmin(np.abs(np_years - t)) for t in desired_ticks]

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
sns.barplot(data=df, x="year", y='value')
plt.xticks(desired_ticks_idx, np_years[desired_ticks_idx])
plt.title("Graph", fontsize=14)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

(In reality, Seaborn's barplot isn't meant for plots that need more bars than the number of labels that fit on the x-axis, optionally rotating them 90 degrees. A lineplot or a stemplot could be an alternative.)